# How to fix "function should not be called directly" error in tidygraph?

Tags: r, error-handling, dplyr, igraph, tidygraph

The problem is when I try to apply a dplyr::mutate function in order to get some measures of centrality to a List of network graphs, iterating thorugh them. I am working with tidygraph.

If I subsett one of the networks of the list, the code works well, my problem is when I try to do it over the whole list. So it is probably somehting related to MAP or LAPPLY functions while iterating over a tbl graph.

```
library (tidyverse)
library (tidygraph)

#My df has the following characteristics
>df
  origin                destination year           amount
1       Colombia           Brasil       2005           16
2       Colombia           US           2005           50
3       Colombia           Argentina    2005           0
4       Colombia           France       2006           5
5       Colombia           US           2006           6
6       Brasil             US           2005           5
7       Brasil             Argentina    2005           7
8       Brasil             France       2006           8
9       Argentina          France       2005           0
10      Argentina          US           2005           10
11      Argentina          France       2006           5      

#This is how I get the network graph list.
Networklist <- df %>% 
  filter(amount>0) %>%             
  group_by(year) %>%              
  group_map(as_tbl_graph)
#Then I apply the functions and that's where I get the error message
Networklist %>%
  map(mutate(degreein = centrality_degree(weights = NULL, mode = "in", loops=FALSE, normalized=FALSE))

#Error: this function should not be called directly
```

I get this error message with many different mapping fuctions I have tried so far, such as map, lmap, lapply, sapply, modify, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you report the output of `dput(df)`?

Comment: or provide a example data for df which results in the issue

Comment: try `map(~ mutate(.x, degreein = centrality_degree(weights = NULL, mode = "in", loops=FALSE, normalized=FALSE)))` you need a lambda to call a function like that in `purrr:map`

Comment: @agila there it is an example. Sorry, I am new.

Comment: @paqmo it worked with your suggestion adding a ~ before mutate! many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To calculate degree centrality without mapping, you need to activate the nodes

```
Networklist %>%
  activate(nodes) %>%
  mutate(degreein = centrality_degree(weights = NULL, mode = "in", loops=FALSE, normalized=FALSE)
```

Then assign it back to Networklist if you want to add it as an attribute.